# Matching 'less than' or 'lessthan or equal to' symbols with regex

Tags: regex, sed

I have trouble matching this pattern <= with a regular expression in sed. What I really need is something like [<|<=] either or type match. I can get it to work with .*, but this occasionally creates other problems with the rest of the line. Example lines would be:

```
for (int j = 0 j < nspec ++j)
```

or

```
for (int j = jmin j <= jmax ++j)
```

The following (partial) commands by way of example.

```
sed -n '/for (int *\([[:graph:]]\) *= *\([[:graph:]]\) *\1 *</p' filename
```

will find the first pattern, but

```
sed -n '/for (int *\([[:graph:]]\) *= *\([[:graph:]]\) *\1 *<=/p' filename
```

Won't find the second.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about the Unicode character '≤'? Does that get left out of the party?

Comment: @Phrogz What programming language considers this valid sourcecode?

Answer (score 2):

Character classes only match *one* character. (This means that `|` is interpreted as a literal pipe character, not alternation)

You need to replace `[]` with `()`:

`(<|<=)` or alternatively: `<=?`

Answer (score 1):

In RegEx the `?` makes the previous element [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).  So `<=?` means "give me less-than, and equals if you have it."

I'm not sure if `?` needs to be escaped in sed or not, so try it both ways, and please let me know/update this when you find out :-)

Comment: Tried it and it does need escaping. however, <=\? finds < but not <=.

Comment: I figured it out.  <=\? does work, but I had an error elsewhere. Here's my full expression for reference: s/for (int *\([[:graph:]]*\) *= *\([[:graph:]]*\) *\1 *<=\? *\([[:graph:]]*\) *++\1)/for \1 in xrange(\2, \3)/